# Usage of "Let" in math

Tags: proof-writing, terminology

Is the usage of "let" in the following parts correct with respect to usage and language?

(1): Let $x \in \mathcal{R}$ . I read that let must always be coupled with "be" (ams.org/publications/authors/AMS-StyleGuide-online.pdf).

(2): Let $x_{t}^{P}$ denote the position of Person P at time t.

Comment: The first example is just bad writing. Lots and lots of that in mathematics. There's nothing wrong with the second one. Whoever told you 'let' must always be coupled with 'be' didn't know what he was talking about.

Comment: I read it in the AMS style guide (https://www.ams.org/publications/authors/AMS-StyleGuide-online.pdf)

Comment: Sorry, I did an update to (2). I meant "Let .. denote" not "Let .. define"

Comment: The [AMS style guide](https://www.ams.org/publications/authors/AMS-StyleGuide-online.pdf) as linked above allows phrases like "_Let $\varepsilon =1/k.$_" see pages 38 and 42.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The first is fine, although it might be read aloud as "Let $x$ be in ${\cal R}$." You could argue that it should more properly be written as something like, "Let $x$ be an element of ${\cal R}$," but it's hard to justify the extra verbiage for something that's already completely clear. The symbol $\in$ denotes set inclusion, not the English phrase "is an element of." If you don't like omitting the verb "to be," (or, effectively using the inclusion symbol $\in$ as a verb rather than an adjective) replace it with something like, "Take $x\in {\cal R}$," or "Fix $x\in {\cal R}$."

The second isn't quite the right usage. If you mean that $x_t$ is the position at time $t$, just write something like, "Define $x_t$ to be the position at time $t$," or, "Let $x_t$ be the position at time $t$." The reader or the author is the one doing the defining, not the number $x_t$. As written, the sentence sounds like the position is just some deterministic function of the time $t$, rather than $x_t$ itself.

Comment: You are right, I meant "let ... denote", actually

Comment: According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Element_(mathematics) : The relation "is an element of", also called set membership, is denoted by the symbol "∈"

Comment: So why you say its not "is an element of" ?

Comment: I mean that the symbol $\in$ is not just an abbreviation for the literal, verbatim four English words "is an element of." In something like "Suppose $x\in {\cal R}$," it's probably read as "is an element of." In something like "Suppose $x, y\in {\cal R}$, it's probably read as "are elements of." And so in something like "Let $x\in {\cal R},$" it's probably read as "be an element of."

Comment: Thats true. So my (1) is ok , if I translate $\in$ as required.

Comment: What about (2) with the updated question ?

Comment: The updated version of (2) is perfectly fine.

Comment: How about "Let f(x) = 2x. It is a linear function..."?

Comment: @FelipeJiménez That should be completely fine (and would be read as something like, "Let $f(x)$ equal $2x$"). Publishers may have their own quirks of style (and some are notoriously picky and arbitrary), but I've never had anyone complain about, let alone reject, one of my submissions for using such an expression without "be."